# "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php

Verán, tengo una clase Noticia y el código de creación me está tirando el error.

El error es el siguiente:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la función de creación es esta:

```
public function crearNoticia($idUsuario, $rutaPortada, string $titulo, string $subtitulo, string $contenidoNoticia, $fechaCreacion, bool $destacada, bool $activa)
    {
        $conexionLiga = $this->conexion;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO t_noticias";
        $sql .= "(id_usuario, ";
        $sql .= "foto_portada, ";
        $sql .= "titulo, ";
        $sql .= "subtitulo, ";
        $sql .= "contenido, ";
        if ($fechaCreacion != null) $sql .= "fecha_creacion, ";
        $sql .= "destacada, ";
        $sql .= "activa) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES ";
        $sql .= "(:id_usuario, ";
        $sql .= ":foto_portada, ";
        $sql .= ":titulo, ";
        $sql .= ":subtitulo, ";
        $sql .= ":contenido, ";
        if ($fechaCreacion != null) $sql .= ":fecha_creacion, ";
        $sql .= ":destacada, ";
        $sql .= ":activa)";

        $statement = $conexionLiga->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id_usuario', $idUsuario);
        $statement->bindParam(':foto_portada', $rutaPortada);
        $statement->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
        $statement->bindParam(':subtitulo', $subtitulo);
        $statement->bindParam(':contenido', $contenidoNoticia);
        if ($fechaCreacion != null) $statement->bindParam(':fecha_creacion', $fechaCreacion);
        $statement->bindParam(':destacada', $destacada);
        $statement->bindParam(':activa', $activa);

        $statement = $conexionLiga->prepare($sql);
        if (parent::ejecutarBien($statement) == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

En el controlador, en el caso del POST, ejecuto este código (se puede apreciar que la cantidad de parámetros que recibe el método crearNoticia() son los mismos):

```
case 'POST':
        //Posibilitar que algunos inputs sean opcionales
            validarInputOpcional($subtitulo,"");
            validarInputOpcional($fecha_creacion,null);
            validarInputOpcional($destacada,false);
            validarInputOpcional($activa,false);

        //Validaciones de inputs
        if (
            validarCambioImagen($foto_portada, $ruta_portada_sin_foto)         == true &&
            validarExtensionImagen($foto_portada, $extensiones_portada)        == true &&
            validarPesoImagen($foto_portada, $maximo_peso_img_portada)         == true &&
            validarImagenSinErrores($foto_portada)                             == true &&
            validarTextoNoVacio($titulo)                                       == true &&
            validarTextoNoVacio($contenido)                                    == true
        ) {
            $rutaConImagen = guardarArchivo($rutaImagenesDeNoticias,$foto_portada,"portada-",null,"");

            var_dump($id_usuario)."<br>";
            var_dump($rutaConImagen)."<br>";
            var_dump($_POST[$titulo])."<br>";
            var_dump($_POST[$subtitulo])."<br>";
            var_dump($_POST[$contenido])."<br>";
            var_dump($_POST[$fecha_creacion])."<br>";
            var_dump($_POST[$destacada])."<br>";
            var_dump($_POST[$activa])."<br>";

            $noticia->crearNoticia($id_usuario, $rutaConImagen, $_POST[$titulo], $_POST[$subtitulo], $_POST[$contenido],$_POST[$fecha_creacion], $_POST[$destacada], $_POST[$activa]);
            //header("location: " . LINK_ADMIN_EDITAR_NOTICIA."?id=".$noticia->ultimoId());
        }
        break;
```

En ese fragmento de código, coloqué var_dump para mostrar los valores que está recibiendo la función. Son los siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué más? La función ejecutarBien() tiene esto (es un execute()):

```
/**
     * Ejecuta la sentencia parametrizada y devuelve true o false si es correcta o con error.
     * @param [type] $statement El cursor.
     * @return bool
     */
    static function ejecutarBien($statement)
    {
        try {
            if (!$statement->execute()) { //si no se ejecuta la consulta...
                print_r($statement->errorInfo()); //imprimir errores
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error de ejecución: \n";
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

También probé ejecutar la consulta en Navicat y funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Las fechas cargan con valores por defecto, son opcionales.

Es lo que puedo mostrar. Y para orientar más, probé con bindParam y bindValue, con ambos no funciona. Probé quitarle el tipado a los parámetros y nada, probé quitar el parámetro de fechaCreacion, probé colocar el método execute() en vez del mío de ejecutarBien(). Ya no sé qué más hacer. Ese método está copiado de otro que me funcionó en otro proyecto.

Comment: Creo que el problema se da cuando no proporcionas la fecha de creación: `if ($fechaCreacion != null) $statement->bindParam(':fecha_creacion', $fechaCreacion);` quedando `:fecha_creacion` sin parámetro asignado. Por cierto, ¿cuál es la línea donde da el error?

Comment: Hola Triby, también pensé que podía ser eso de la fecha de creación, pero la saqué y el problema siguió igual. Y la línea de error, tira error en el "if (!$statement->execute())" del método ejecutarBien. Si lo cambio por un simple execute() en la función de crear, tira el error en el execute(). El error siempre salta ahí. :(

Comment: Quitaste la línea de fecha de creación, pero ¿dejaste el parámetro `:fecha_creacion` en la consulta? También debiste quitarlo.

Comment: Sí lo quité de todas partes. :C Y me gustaría dejarlo así opcional, por si en un futuro quisiera agregar una fecha de creación futura para calendarizar a más adelante la publicación de la noticia.

Comment: ¿Cuáles variables te dan _NULL_ con `var_dump()`?

Comment: $_POST["fecha_creación"], lo dejo en nulo con mi función "validarInputOpcional($fecha_creacion,null);", entonces pasa como nula a la función de crearNoticia().

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112581/discussion-between-ororok-and-triby).

Comment: Hola. Prueba a usar esta alternativa: usar un array de parámetros con nombre así: `$parametros = [':id_usuario' => leerValorEnPost('id_usuario', $default), ...];` preparas los hallders del query así `$values = 'VALUES ('.implode(', ', array_keys($parametros)).')'; ` pegas values dentro del query, creas la sentencia preparada y ejecutas directo `$statement->execute($parametros);` no necesitas hacer bind, PDO sabe hacerlo. **Debes pasar el default que te convenga** para cada parámetro en el método leerValorEnPost($clave, $default) que hará lectura o asignará el default si no encuentra o es nulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toda la variable **`$statement`** se vacia en la siguiente línea casi al final

```
$statement = $conexionLiga->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: ¿Neta? ¿Me puedes decir cómo debería dejarlo? Porque el método lo copie de otro que funcionaba. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
public function crearNoticia($idUsuario, $rutaPortada, string $titulo, string $subtitulo, string $contenidoNoticia, $fechaCreacion, bool $destacada, bool $activa)
{
    $conexionLiga = $this->conexion;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO t_noticias";
    $sql .= "(id_usuario, ";
    $sql .= "foto_portada, ";
    $sql .= "titulo, ";
    $sql .= "subtitulo, ";
    $sql .= "contenido, ";
    if ($fechaCreacion != null) $sql .= "fecha_creacion, ";
    $sql .= "destacada, ";
    $sql .= "activa) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES ";
    $sql .= "(:id_usuario, ";
    $sql .= ":foto_portada, ";
    $sql .= ":titulo, ";
    $sql .= ":subtitulo, ";
    $sql .= ":contenido, ";
    if ($fechaCreacion != null) $sql .= ":fecha_creacion, ";
    $sql .= ":destacada, ";
    $sql .= ":activa)";

    $statement = $conexionLiga->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':id_usuario', $idUsuario);
    $statement->bindParam(':foto_portada', $rutaPortada);
    $statement->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
    $statement->bindParam(':subtitulo', $subtitulo);
    $statement->bindParam(':contenido', $contenidoNoticia);
    if ($fechaCreacion != null) $statement->bindParam(':fecha_creacion', $fechaCreacion);
    $statement->bindParam(':destacada', $destacada);
    $statement->bindParam(':activa', $activa);

    if (parent::ejecutarBien($statement) == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no puedo creer que me haya tardado tanto tiempo sin ver esa línea de código. u.u Ya está funcionando... que vergüenza.